# Handling authentication errors on the client side

Tags: rest, authentication, backbone.js, jersey, dropwizard

Currently we are working on a REST application, using Dropwizard on the server side and RequireJS, Backbone on the client side.

Our authentication model is cookie-based. On every request a web filter checks for the appropriate cookie and its value, the token. If the token is still valid, it will forward the request on the filter chain, if it isn't it will respond with 401.

On the client side it ends up like:

```
do an ajax request:
    success:
        render the rest of the content
    error: // got 401
        stop whatever you were doing and redirect to the login page
```

The only flaw showed up with this approach was that the client first have to download the actual page before it gets redirected to the login page (in case of 401 of course).

For example, I have two pages a.html and b.html. If client is browsing page *a.html* and after some time its token expires, first he need to download *b.html* which will execute an ajax request in the background (see above) and then I will be able to redirect it to the login page:

```
a.html (200) -> token expired -> b.html (200) -> login.html (200)
```

So far I was using such style of error handling in every REST application we wrote. What I would like to see is for example:

```
a.html (200) -> token expired -> login.html (200)
```

but this would require for example, hard-coding the login page url in the server side filter and generally, tying some logic into the server side code.

I'm sure there are better ways to handle server authentication errors on the client side and I would like to know about them.

Answer (score 0):

why do you not use Dropwizard built in authentication[1]? As stated in the mailing list[2] youn can write your own BasicAuthProvider in which you would then have access to the HttpContext.

Hope it helps.

Bye, Piero

[1]http://dropwizard.codahale.com/manual/auth/

[2]https://groups.google.com/d/msg/dropwizard-user/NyvxbefQ1FE/vexCdTHdFuYJ